# How to load a image from project in WKWebView HTML

Tags: ios, swift, applet, wkwebview, swift5

I am trying to load an image in the assets folder of my project through an html file in a WKWebview.

Nothing has worked out. Could you please help me out?

This is how I am accessing the image. Image is in same folder as html doc.

```
<img src="image_name.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

1. You can upload to cloud and give the path try here https://imgur.com/upload

```
<img src="cloud path" />
```

2. Keep a full local path and provide it in html tag

```
/Users/abc/Documents/Swift/Test/Banner1.png
```